# userFunc in TYPO3 displaying the rendered list but not storing in the DB

Tags: typo3, backend

The TCA field for one of my records is as follows :

```
'page_id' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:calendar/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_calendar_domain_model_display.page_id',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'user',
                'userFunc' => 'EXT:calendar/class.tx_calendars_tca.php:tx_calendars_tca->someWizard',
            ),
```

The function `someWizard` looks like this :

```
    function someWizard($PA, $fObj) {


        $content='<select>' .
                '<option value="One" > item 1 </option>' .
                '<option value="Two" > item 2 </option>' .
                '<option value="Three" > item 55 </option>' .
                '</select>';


        return $content;
}
```

The select list renders fine into the backend form, but it does not store anything when saved.It might be that the list is being displayed but the values are not getting set.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to get all the pages title into a drop-down list, with some conditions and processing. The pseudo code of what i'm thinking to do is something like this.(I still need to do lot of processing to the list)

```
function someWizard($PA, $fObj) {


                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = TRUE;
                $formField='<select>';  
                 $PA['fieldConf']['config']['type'] = 'select';

                try{
                    $where='is_siteroot=1';
                    $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*','pages',$where);
                    while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                        $formField.='<option value='.$row['uid'].'>'.$row['title'].'</option>';
                    }
                }

                catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e;
                }


                $formField.='</select>';
                return $formField;

    }
```

If in my TCA, I give `'type' => 'select'` it doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using will of course just show the selector. Even if this construct would be able to save the data, you would have to provide at least some basic information about where to store it. So at least a "name" attribute for the "select" would be cool.

You should change the field type to "select" instead of user and use itemsProcFunc to manipulate the array of available items.

Find more information here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/

Comment: are you talking about the `name` attribute for the `<option>` tags or something related to `$PA` array? 

Thanks for the answer, please check the edit :)

Comment: The select tag needs a name, otherwise the datamap processor will not know how to handle that stuff. And of course it should match the "official" naming scheme for TCE form fields, which is why I recommended the select type. In this case you wouldn't even need an itemsProcFunc - see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html for a detailed description of select and its parameters.

To get items from "pages" based on some additional where clause you should go for the stuff defined in "foreign_table" and "foreign_table_where" instead of creating a userFunc.

Answer (score 0):

The element has no name so there is no chance to be stored. If you only want to modify the items in the list, go with **Joey's** answer. If you want to change the configuration of the field somewhat more depending on some criteria (e.g. from a select box if there is many items to checkboxes if there's only few), the best is to use TYPO3's method to create the element:

```
function someWizard($PA, $fObj) {
  $PA['fieldConf']['config']['type'] = 'select';
  $content = $fobj->getSingleField_typeInput('TABLE_NAME', $PA['field'], false, $PA);
  return $content;
}
```

- Replace **TABLE_NAME** with the name of your table.
- Leave all the other default configuration in your TCA setup.
- Debug `$PA` to see what's inside and what you should change on the fly.

Comment: Well, that certainly falls in what I want to do. 
I edited my question. Please check. Thank You :)

Comment: It seems to me that you are only manipulating the items in which case go for Joey's suggestion. If you really do need to change TCA on the fly, then go for mine. The way it works is that in your default TCA you use the `'type' => 'user'` plus the `userFunc` plus possibly some other configuration for the element that you will be rendering (e.g. `maxitems` for the `select` type). Your method than changes the `type` to the one that you actually want to get and uses `getSingleField_typeInput()` to correctly render the element.

Comment: Do `print_r($PA)` to see what's inside and what you can modify in whatever way you want.